# Adding multiple rows to database from dynamic field event

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a dynamic event in JS in my form which adds another block of fields so my users can add another address:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var $address = $('#address');
    var num = $('.clonedAddress').length; 
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
    var newElem = $address.clone().attr('id', 
    'address' + newNum).addClass('clonedAddress');

//set all div id's and the input id's
newElem.children('div').each (function (i) {
this.id = 'input' + (newNum*11 + i);
    });

newElem.find('input').each (function () {
this.id = this.id + newNum;
this.name = this.name + newNum;
    });

    if (num > 0) {
        $('.clonedAddress:last').after(newElem);
    } else {
        $address.after(newElem);
    }


    $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

    if (newNum == 3) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
$('#btnDel').click(function() {
    $('.clonedAddress:last').remove();
    $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
    if ($('.clonedAddress').length == 0) {
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

However, when I put my form action the page just refreshes when I click my 'add another address' button:

```
<form action="address.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
```

These are my fields:

```
if(empty($err)) {
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
       $Street = $_POST['Street'][$i];
       $Line2 = $_POST['Line2'][$i];
       $Line3 = $_POST['Line3'][$i];
       $Town = $_POST['Town'][$i];
       $Postcode = $_POST['Postcode'][$i];
       $Country = $_POST['Country'][$i];
       $Tele = $_POST['Tele'][$i];
       $Fax = $_POST['Fax'][$i];
       $Type = $_POST['Type'][$i];
       $Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'][$i];
$sql_insert = "INSERT into `address`
       (`Street`,`Line2`,`Line3`,`Town`, `Postcode` ,`Country`,`Tele`,`Fax`,`Type`
       ,`Mobile`            )
VALUES
       ('$Street','$Line2','$Line3','$Town','$Postcode','$Country',
       '$Tele','$Fax','$Type', '$Mobile'
    )";
mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());     
    }
```

I want all addresses to go to mysql database.
I hope this is clear

Comment: Can you show this `add another address`-button, as well? You did not by any chance define it as `<input type="submit" />`, did you? And on a related note: PLEASE sanatize string values before inserting into mysql queries. You are trivially prune to SQL injection attacks. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: ive got four buttons, an add address, remove address, submit form (to my database) and clear form. `<p align="center">
<button id="btnAdd">Add Address</button>
<button id="btnDel">Delete Address</button>
</p>
<p align="center">
 <input name="doAddress" type="submit" id="doAddress" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Define buttons as followed: `<input type="button" value="ButtonLabel" />`.

My short test resulted in my `<button>` getting treated as submit type input by firefox. This means `<button>FooBar</button>` and `<input type="submit" value="FooBar" />` are equivalent.

You might also want to simplify your javascript code. You can use the array notation for input names:

```
<input type="text" name="street[]" />
<input type="text" name="zip[]" />

<input type="text" name="street[]" />
<input type="text" name="zip[]" />
```

will result in `$_POST["street"][0]` and `$_POST["street"][1]` beeing filled with the user's input. This is what you want judging from your php code, anyway.

You don't need ids for all your input tags. Just keep one full set of inputs for one address and append this to your form. Maybe something like:

```
$('#address').append(
    '<div>' + 
    '<input type="text" name="street[]" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="zip[]" />' +
    '</div>'
);
```

Or just have a full set hidden on your page and clone it, then append. I'm sure our jQuery pros will know a better solution.

And finally: Please sanatize your input with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$Street = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Street'][$i]);
// and so on for the other values.
```

Comment: Yes I already have my inputs like this `<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="input">
Street<span class="required">*</span> 
<input name="Street[]"  type="text" id="Street">
</div>`
The button works now thanks. When I submit I have these errors:
`Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\dbc.php on line 100`
Line 100 is- `$('.clonedAddress:last').remove();`
`Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\address.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\address.php on line 34` etc

Comment: You cannot have multiple input's with the same id (`id="Street"`) in a valid html document. You **don't need** ids, anyway.

Comment: `Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\dbc.php on line 100` Seems like you passed an `array` instead of a `string` to `strip_tags` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\dbc.php` on line `100`. Glad to help!

Comment: `function filter($data) {
 $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
 
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 
 $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
 
 return $data;
}`

Comment: What's `dbc`? I'm not good at clairvoyance but I think you may did something like `strip_tags($_POST['Street'])` instead of `strip_tags($_POST['Street'][$i])` and the notice might be from your `for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)`-loop. You might want to change it to `for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["Street"]); $i++)` to only try and insert as many addresses as you got input.

Comment: ah thanks your  a star. Now I've got the problem of 30 rows being added!

Comment: Again. Im not good at clairvoyance. Just post another question with the code, that is not working or edit your current question, if your problem is still related.